# ASP.NET forms authentication is screwy after RewritePath

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, authentication, forms-authentication

I have a problem which I can't replicate on my dev server (IIS 8.5), but which is happening on my live server.

The ASP.NET website uses forms authentication, which works perfectly unless the URL is rewritten. On rewritten URLs, the user is not considered logged in. If you click "log in", then the user is logged in without redirecting to the login form! This means the cookie is somehow being used to authenticate the user after clicking "log in". Refreshing the rewritten page reverts to not being logged in.

Here are some concrete examples:

Go to http://www.paraglidingmap.com and log in with the following details (top right of the screen):

Username: test

Password: hibiscus

Now go to this page which uses URL redirection, and you will not be logged in! But if you click "log in", you will be magically logged in until you refresh the page.
http://www.paraglidingmap.com/page/AppAndroid

Someone out there must be smarter than me. Why is this only happening on the live server and not dev?  I have checked that integrated pipeline is used on both servers.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.  Instead of using HttpContext.Current.RewritePath, using Context.Server.TransferRequest seems to also transfer the request cookie.

I would be grateful if anyone could explain why this is the case.